# How to recompile gradle dependency from sources?

Tags: gradle

We have a dependency *dep* which was originally compiled in Java 8. The project requiring this dependency is compiled and run with Java 6. This results ``bad major version'' error.

We have the sources available in our central repository for dep and looking for a way that the sources are downloaded in build.gradle:

```
compile('dep_group:dep_artifact:version:sources')
```

and then recompile in JDK 6 to produce the required jar file.

Is it possible? Or any suggestions?

Alternatively, we have to download the code of dep offline, recompile with JDK 6, publish the jar file and finally add it as a dependency. But we are looking to avoid this long route. This is just for testing purposes and we do not want to publish a new version compiled with an older version of Java.

Answer (score 1):

Without original build file (POM / build.gradle / ant.xml) you cannot recompile library. If it is a rather simple library - possible option is to include its sources as additional module in multi-module Gradle project:

1. Download sources
2. Create folder for them in your project
3. Create additional module as described in Gradle docs: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html
4. Apply java plugin for module
5. Set dependency on this project in format: compile(project(':dep'))

Finally, when you build your project Gradle will compile this module and use it as dependency for your main module.

Do not forget to check library license, e.g. Apache License 2 permits such a simple usage of sources.